# CSS Flex Print Issue

Tags: css, printing, flexbox

I tried printing with chrome but i got some issue. Google chrome print not reading the flex property of my css also the bold property is not being read.

any solution or alternative code to make this work or any pdf print library that i can implement my page

Comment: We cannot know the reason for this without seeing relevant code. It would be more useful to future readers if a proper explanation of the problem was found instead of the workaround given in the current answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to define some special print styles as a browser will override certain styles when printing.

Within a CSS document you can do:

```css
@media print {
  /* All your print styles go here */
}
```

Or just link to a separate print stylesheet

```html
<link href="/path/to/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing